# Error when generating getters and setters doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I would like to generate getters and setters automatically with Doctrine, I've tried to use this command line

`docker-compose exec php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App`

but I get this error everytime

> Cannot rename "/srv/api/src/Entity2/Canton.phpJFKBPB" to
>   "/srv/api/src/Entity2/Canton.php"

Anybody understand why ?

Thanks

Comment: Run docker php container like this: 
docker exec -ti container_name bash
then inside container using console command.

Comment: Or try run as root with -ti flag.

Comment: I still got the same error message.

Comment: Did you setup file permissions  on var folder? How about other console command.  Are working on other commands?

Comment: I didn't setup permissions, but I am using Api-platform. Others commands are working, I can generate entities from db for example